# Joomla VirtueMart: English words appear when german language choosed

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, virtuemart

I install successfully „`de-DE.com_virtuemart.zip`“ and „de-`DE.VirtueMart_Plugins_Language_Pack.zip`“) but some english words appeared when i change the language locator to German.

Why some  words like "Items(s)" bei cart and „Search Enter Keywords“ are not translated?

Does somebody face already this issue? Thanks for any information

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your versions of Joomla and Virtuemart it is possible that the words that aren't translated are the result of the selected language not have matching translations so Joomla/Virtuemart fall back to the English default.

Language files in Joomla are generally based of an original English language file and if the component is using current standard you will find it's language files in component's directory.

e.g.

```
/administrator/components/com_example/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_example.ini
/administrator/components/com_example/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_example.sys.ini
/components/com_example/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_example.ini
```

The example above shows the English language file paths for both the `/administrator` or back-end and the front end of an example component.

If the component uses the older style of `language` file placement (like Virtuemart) you will find the files in `/language/en-GB/` and `/administrator/language/en-GB/`

[Language files](http://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files) are UTF-8 `ini` files that have a `KEY` and a `String for translation.` e.g. here's a line from `/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_virtuemart.ini`

```
COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_ADD_TO="Add to Cart"
```

In the Virtuemart example the `KEY` is the left side of the `=` de-DE, i.e. `COM_VIRTUEMART_CART_ADD_TO` while the English translation for that key is the right side `Add to Cart`.

As you've probably guessed your `de-DE` is the German language identifier.

To find the `KEYS` that aren't translated properly, you will need to look in the corresponding views `tmpl` files (`components/com_virtuemart/views/viewname/tmpl/`).

You will be looking for bits of `php` in the `tmpl` files that look like this:

```
<?php echo JText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_COMMENT_CART'); ?>
```

That is from `cart/tmpl/default.php`